# TypeError: a is undefined with Select2 plugin in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-select2

I create my Select on the on change event of another dropdown, so here is my script:

```
$ddlOther.on('change', function(e) {
        var Json = {},
            persons = [];
        Json.id = $(this).val();

        $.post('/PersonController/GetPersonDDL', Json, function(data) {
            drivers = data;
        }, 'json').done(function(data) {
            $person.select2({
                placeholder: "Select Persons(s)",
                allowClear: true,
                multiple: true,
                data:  persons
            });
        });
    });
```

This is my controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetPersonDDL(JsonDictionary args)
{
     JsonResult result = null;

     string id= args["id"].Trim();

     var persons = _context.Persons
                           .Where(x => x.id== id)
                            .Select(x => new 
                                             { x.first_name, 
                                               x.middle_name, 
                                               x.last_name, x.id
                                              }).ToList();


     foreach (var person in persons)
     {
             var item = new SelectListItem
             {
                   Text = string.Format("{0} - {1} {2} {3}", 
                                                          person.id, 
                                                          person.first_name, 
                                                          person.middle_name,
                                                          person.last_name),
                    Value = person.id

                    };

                    list.Add(item);
                }

      result = Json(list.Select(x=>new {value = x.Text, 
                                        id = x.Value}
                                ), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


      return result;
}
```

I get data back, but the console (firebug in this case) gives me the error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

The `JSON` returned looks like this:

```
[ 
  Object { value="John Doe", id="1"}, 
  Object { value="Jane Doe" id="2"} 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 expects `[{text="john doe",id="1"},{text="jane doe",id="2"}]`,

so in my controller, I just changed it to return:

`result = Json(list.Select(x=>new {value = x.Text, 
                                        id = x.Value}
                                ), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

It works now by changing the controller, but if you want so specify a different name for the text, you can change Select2's text parameter:

`text : 'value'`,

but I did not get it to work this way, so if anyone knows, pleas chime in.